# Xcode Using Auto Layout does not optimize the screen for each iphone model

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

Good morning.
I have a problem creating a storyboard with AutoLayout.

I created a scroll view with Auto Layout.
The width of the scroll view is equal to the width of the screen.
The height is 0.33 times of the height of the screen.

On the storyboard, select View as: iphone8
When I upload the app to iphone8, the scroll view appears in the size I intended.

But if I upload to a other phone like iphone8+ or iponeX or ipad,
The scroll view size appears in the size applied to the iPhone 8.

In the storyboard, select View as: iphoneX
Upload to iphoneX and the screen will appear as intended.

I don't know if it's a xcode bug or if I'm misunderstanding Autolayout ...
I thought it would be ok if I uploaded it to the App Store and downloaded it.

but nothing happend.

My xcode version is 11.

Please help me...!

Comment: Please post your codes or any screenshots of what you currently have or what you like to achieve, this will help others to understand your problem better.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are understanding auto layouts wrong. But this is just an assumption made due to not seeing any code . Just because you enable auto layouts it doesnt mean your app is going to be universal on each mobile phone. Think of auto layouts as a "lizard" that changes the colors according to the environment he lives in . You still have to give him the environment so he can adapt.

Likewise you still have to give the constraints to your views on one device . What it does is it uses those constraints and enables auto layouts to adapt to different mobile phones. So if in case you see a view which has 8px from the top margin in an iphone 5s it will ensure that you will have 8px from an iphone 7s+ as well.

What it really does is adapt not remake. Refer to the links below , this article describes about the use of auto layouts pretty well.

Note - if you have already done this give us some code to look into so we can be more descriptive . Good Luck !

https://medium.com/swift-india/understanding-auto-layout-item-relationships-b08a0e5689f0

Comment: Thank you all for your kind reply.

I think I found a problem.

The problem was the xib file that goes inside the scrollview.

The xib file created separately does not seem to have autolayout applied.

Instead of creating a separate xib file, I created a layout programmatically to insert it into the scroll view, and the screen began to appear as intended.

If you are experiencing the same problem, please refer to it.

Thank you very much for answering the question.

Comment: makes sense now , i was note aware of a xib file . My pleasure to help in anyway :)